# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , o.default) is not a function: What's causing it?

Tags: reactjs

In my create react app project I'm running into the following error in my production build (not in my dev build):

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , o.default) is not a function
>       at Object.e.f.(:4444/anonymous function)...

I've been investigating this bug for a couple of hours but struggle to find out how to debug this uglified piece of js.

What makes it tough is that the error returns **o**.default and not **SomeLibrary**.default so I don't really know where to start my search really...

What does that **o**.default mean in this case? Any tips for figuring out what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 41):

It seems to be import statement somewhere in your file is incorrect.

Example: (from an [issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/116))

```
// fails
import combineReducers from "redux"

// correct
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
```

> What makes it tough is that the error returns o.default and not SomeLibrary.default so I don't really know where to start my search really...

There's nothing but exported in some library just as `o`. Example default export:

```
export default {
  o: something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who tried the solution above and still cannot solve this problem, you might be importing the library successfully and then using the library in a function that is located in the same file.

But, if you export that file and import it to another file, that is where you might be having a problem.

Simply import your already exported file as -

```js
import {myComponent} from "/util/http"
```

instead of -

```js
import myComponent from "/util/http"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone, in my case I was using React component inside a JS file which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening for anyone with Auth.signIn using aws-amplify, please try the below update for aws-amplify. This worked as a permanent fix and didn't break any of my current code.

```
sudo npx npm-check-updates -i '/@?aws-amplify/' && npm update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone accidentally misnamed their file and stumbled across this post:

This also happens sometimes if you are using TypeScript with ReactJS/React Native and have a component or hook filename ending with `.ts` instead of `.tsx`, especially with the imports in test files and if you are using `jest` or React testing library. Component or hook filenames should always have the `.tsx` extension.